The TIMESTAMP column in V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS table in Oracle DB is based on DBTimezone or Server timezone
Scenario: Oracle DB is in the UTC timezone but the Server on which DB is hosted is in the UTC+01:00.
Now when I query the table V$LOGMNR_CONTENTS for the column TIMESTAMP on which timezone is this based on? The server timezone or DB timezone?

already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62477322/timezone-for-commit-timestamp-in-vlogmnr-contents
